# Why do C++ streams treat bools as numerics?

Tags: c++, io, boolean

In C++, the stream I/O libraries do not by default print "true" or "false" when you output a `bool`, but rather "1" or "0".  Instead, one is required to explicitly request a word-based printing, via `std::boolalpha`/`std::noboolalpha`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << bool{ false }; //Prints "0"
    std::cout << std::boolalpha; //Print all bools with alphanumerics
    std::cout << bool{ false }; //Prints "false"
    std::cout << std::noboolalpha; //Return to default
}
```

Leaving aside whether this is appropriate as a default (it's definitely confusing for beginners), I'm not sure why C++ offers the `bool`-as-numeric functionality at all.  Some plausible reasons I can think of:

- The mess of standardizing `bool` between C89, C99, and C++, might have meant that an overload for `operator<<` could not distinguish between `bool`s and `int`s,
- Primitive localization support ("true" in English is not the same as "Wahr" in German, but "1" is "1" everywhere...that uses Arabic numerals), or just
- The "output parameter" problem when serializing to disk (`std::ofstream{"filename"} << static_cast<int>(my_bool_variable);` isn't particularly onerous, but the input analogue requires a temporary variable.)

In any case, I can't find the actual (historical) reason on the web; for example, the topic is never address in the C++FAQ, for example.  So: **Why does C++ offer this `bool`-as-numeric functionality in its input/output streams?**

Comment: On the contrary, I think that all three of these are actually *very good* reasons for the default behavior.

Comment: You're making a few assertions that are false. (1) C89 never had a standardised `bool` type. (2)  `bool`, `true` and `false` were introduced as keywords by C++ with a "unique signed integral type" as an ANSI resolution reported in the ARM  (3) C99 introduced `bool`, etc as macros rather than keywords because they didn't want to introduce incompatibility with older C code that defined its own `bool` type or macros. (3)  C++ streams - even as originally introduced in pre-standard `<iostream.h>` - had `operator<<()` overloads that could distinguish between `bool` and `int`.

Comment: JaMiT & Sam Varshavchik: Thanks for the advice.  I've removed the opinionated statement.

Comment: Actual boolean algebra uses the symbols 0 and 1. So it's not *that* farfetched to have them here. Confusion notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout << bool{b}` uses [`std::use_facet<std::num_put<char>>(std::cout.getloc()).put(std::cout, std::cout, std::cout.fill(), bool{b})`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put) to do the actual output.

What this does is basically make a printf specifier and print that (modified by flags).

This is speculation, but it might be because in C++98 when this was originally standardised (and probably in pre-standard C++), the boolean type in C was `int`, so `printf("%d", 0 == 0);` output `1`. (This is still the case with `_Bool` which promotes to `int`). So C++ wanted to treat `bool`s as numeric types in this specific case (Especially since it uses a *numeric* facet of the locale), and just use the printf specifier of `%d`, to match what would be output in the corresponding C code.

Note that `std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << true;` outputs `00001` (possibly even with commas/spaces/full stops depending on the locale). Without `std::boolalpha`, `std::cout << bool{b}` is literally equivalent to `std::cout << static_cast<int>(bool{b})`, just like the C variadic argument promotions.

Also, localisation support is available by modifying the `std::numpunct` facet of the locale and overriding [`std::numpunct<CharT>::do_truename` and `do_falsename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/truefalsename). But this is orthogonal to whether the default behaviour should be `std::boolalpha`.